# RoR 4 isolated engine, asset overrides not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an isolated engine (RoR 4) which has it's own css and javascript manifests and assets like so (apologies for the formatting):

```
app
|--assets
   |-- javascripts
       |-- my_engine
           |-- application.js
           |-- master.js
           |-- extend.js
   |-- stylesheets
       |-- my_engine
           |-- application.css
           |-- master.scss
           |-- extend.scss
```

**The manifest files:**

application.js

```
//= require ./master
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require ./master
*= require_tree .
```

The purpose of the `extend` file in both instances is to provide the main app an avenue to add functionality (js) or styling (css) to views within the engine by overriding these files in:

```
main_app
|-- vendor
    |-- assets
        |-- javascripts
            |-- my_engine
                |-- extend.js
```

and

```
main_app
|-- vendor
    |-- assets
        |-- stylesheets
            |-- my_engine
                |-- extend.scss
```

This works perfectly in development, but in production both extend files are being ignored and none of the additional behaviour or styling is being applied. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong and why it works in one environment and not another?

Comment: Where do you require extend ?

Comment: I previously had a `require ./extend` in both manifest files, but it made no difference; the behaviour was exactly the same ie. works in development, ignored in production.